# QProgressBar displaying lines in background, when I ran application on the embedded device

Tags: qt

I have to show the QProgressBar with smooth blue color [without any lines or text in background]

when I ran the application on the host PC the Progress bar is displaying properly without the lines, But when complied for the embedded device and ran on the device the progress bar displaying with a lines.

Qt progress bar orientation = vertical.

[image: vertical progress bar displaying on the embedded device]

[image: vertical progress bar want to display on the embedded device]

Could any one help me, how to fix this issue in the embedded device.

I Have Resolved this Issue by adding the below line :

```
ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk {background-color:rgb(0,112,241);}")
```

Comment: Is `css` really an appropriate tag?

Comment: Qt version? Embedded OS? Embedded OS Windowing system?

Comment: Qt 5.0.2 , Debian OS , Linux Platform.

Comment: I have resolved this Issue  by adding the  QProgressBar::chunk {background-color:rgb(0,112,241);}

Comment: If you have a solution for your own problem, please post it as an answer. **Answer's don't belong in the question, nor in the comments.**